# Magento 2 - How to insert logo into custom pdf

Tags: magento2, product, pdf, stores, logo

I am trying to print logo into custom pdf through controller. I am able to print product name, sku etc.But I don't know how to add store logo. My code is as below. Can anyone please help me to add store logo into custom pdf as I have logo URL but don't know how to insert them. Thanks in advance.

```
$logoURl = $this->_logo->getLogoSrc(); //logo URL
$productName = $product->getName(); //Product Name
$productSku = $product->getSku(); //Product SKU

$pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
$page = $pdf->newPage(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
$pdf->pages[] = $page;
$page->setFont(\Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA), 20);
$page->drawText($logoURl, 10, 500); //Able to print Logo URL
$page->drawText($productName, 10, 400); //Able to print product name
$page->drawText($productSku, 10, 350); //Able to print product SKU
$pdfData = $pdf->render();

header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=result.pdf");
header("Content-type: application/x-pdf");

echo $pdfData;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `drawImage` instead of `drawText` function.

Try :

```
    $folderName = \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image\Logo::UPLOAD_DIR;
    $storeLogoPath = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
        'design/header/mobile_logo_src',
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
    $path = $folderName . '/' . $storeLogoPath;
    $logoUrl = $this->_urlBuilder
            ->getBaseUrl(['_type' => \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA]) . $path;
    if ($logoUrl) {
        if (is_file($logoUrl)) {
           $pdfImage = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($logoUrl);
           $page->drawImage($pdfImage, 10, 500);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Vinz, thanks for your answer. I used above code and I get "Cannot create image resource. File not found" error. 
Can you please suggest what needs to be done.

Comment: It seems that your `$logoURl` is not good. Are you sure that your path is the right ?

Comment: Yes path is correct because when I echo $logoURL and check same URL in browser, I am able to access logo with $logoURL

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: Hi Vinz, thanks again. Does this "Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/identity/logo', $store)" work in magento 2?

Comment: Woops my bad, was thinking in M1, edited for M2

Comment: mobile_logo_src is your Image name ?

Comment: @HaFizUmer It's config created, to try it you can set your path in ```$storeLogoPath```.

Answer (score 0):

After spending sometime, I got to know to print logo into custom pdf using logoURL.
My mistake was that I was considering relative path of logo URL and not the application path. Hence I was getting error.
For exam : 
If I am working on ubunto machine localhost and my project folder name is abc with logo.png inside it just in directory where there is app folder. Then I should consider path as "/var/www/html/abc/logo.png" and not "http://127.0.0.1/abc/logo.png"
I changed path to /var/www/html/abc/logo.png and was able to print logo into custom pdf.

Writing piece of code lines here below to understand better

$pdfImage = \Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath("/var/www/html/abc/logo.png");

$page->drawImage($pdfImage, 10, 600);

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This**

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

protected $scopeConfig;

protected $fileFactory;

public function __construct(
    ................................................>
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
    ................................................>
) {
    ................................................>
    $this->_mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
    ................................................>
}

public function execute()
{
    $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
    // $zendImage = new \Zend_Pdf_Image();
    $pdf->pages[] = $pdf->newPage(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
    $page = $pdf->pages[0]; // this will get reference to the first page.
    $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
    $style->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0, 0, 0));
    $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES);

    $width = $page->getWidth();
    $hight = $page->getHeight();
    $x = 30;
    $pageTopalign = 850; //default PDF page height
    $this->y = 850 - 100; //print table row from page top – 100px

    $style->setFont($font, 10);
    $page->setStyle($style);

    $folderName = \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image\Logo::UPLOAD_DIR;

    $path = $folderName . '/logo.jpg';

    $pdfImage = \Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($path));

    $top = 800;
    //top border of the page
    $widthLimit = 270;
    //half of the page width
    $heightLimit = 265;
    //assuming the image is not a "skyscraper"
    $width = $pdfImage->getPixelWidth();
    $height = $pdfImage->getPixelHeight();

    //preserving aspect ratio (proportions)
    $ratio = $width / $height;
    if ($ratio > 1 && $width > $widthLimit) {
        $width = $widthLimit;
        $height = $width / $ratio;
    } elseif ($ratio < 1 && $height > $heightLimit) {
        $height = $heightLimit;
        $width = $height * $ratio;
    } elseif ($ratio == 1 && $height > $heightLimit) {
        $height = $heightLimit;
        $width = $widthLimit;
    }

    $y1 = $top - $height;
    $y2 = $top;
    $x1 = 30;
    $x2 = $x1 + $width;

    $page->drawImage($pdfImage, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);

    $fileName = 'example.pdf';

    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=result.pdf");

    header("Content-type: application/x-pdf");

    // echo $pdf->render();

    $this->fileFactory->create(
        $fileName,
        $pdf->render(),
        \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
        'application/pdf'
    );
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***