# How create Custom Pdf in magento 2 Like invoice , Shipment

Tags: magento2, module, custom, pdf

I want to create custom pdf with custom **text or media**

can anyone suggestion me any best link or some help 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check below link
1) https://meetanshi.com/blog/generate-pdf-programmatically-magento-2/
2) [Magento 2: Convert HTML code into PDF file and Download?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153080/magento-2-convert-html-code-into-pdf-file-and-download)
3) https://webkul.com/blog/generate-pdf-programmatically-magento2/

Comment: @HaFiz Umer check this links.

Comment: Now i want to insert some images in the pdf . how can add images also ?

Comment: You can use $page->drawImage() instead of  $page->drawText(). see more details on this link :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/259663/magento-2-how-to-insert-logo-into-custom-pdf

Answer (score 2):

> **You Can Check Below Link**

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ORs80r5okZoWdQqLi1gJtlUZ6UH4luBs1SN0YRioiD0/edit

**app/code/VendoreName/RmaPdfPrint/Controller/Rma**

**PrintAction.php**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace VendoreName\RmaPdfPrint\Controller\Rma;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use VendoreName\Rma\Api\Repository\RmaRepositoryInterface;
use VendoreName\Rma\Api\Service\Rma\RmaManagement\SaveInterface;
use VendoreName\Rma\Helper\Controller\Rma\GuestStrategy;
use VendoreName\Rma\Helper\Controller\Rma\StrategyFactory;
use VendoreName\Rma\Service\Config\FrontendConfig;
use VendoreName\RmaPdfPrint\Block\DownloadRmaPdf;

class PrintAction extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
{
    protected $rmaData;

    private $guestStrategy;
    private $rmaRepository;
    private $rmaSaveManagement;
    private $registry;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        GuestStrategy $guestStrategy,
        RmaRepositoryInterface $rmaRepository,
        SaveInterface $rmaSaveManagement,
        Registry $registry,
        StrategyFactory $strategyFactory,
        Session $customerSession,
        FrontendConfig $frontendConfig,
        DownloadRmaPdf $rmaData
    ) {
        $this->guestStrategy     = $guestStrategy;
        $this->rmaRepository     = $rmaRepository;
        $this->rmaSaveManagement = $rmaSaveManagement;
        $this->registry          = $registry;
        $this->rmaData           = $rmaData;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $rma = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $this->registry->register('current_rma', $rma);
        $this->rmaSaveManagement->markAsReadForCustomer($rma);
        $pdf = $this->rmaData->getPdf($rma); // Here We set RMA Data
        $pdf->render();
        $pdfData = $pdf->render();

        header('Content-type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=result.pdf');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

        echo $pdfData;
    }
}
```

> Must Open link whole code are in the file